# What is the use of ANALYZE TABLE key word in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Can it used to repair mysql index. I am facing performance issues even for queries that use index

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your version of **MySQL** and storage engine but in general:

**OPTIMIZE TABLE** Analyzes table, stores the key distribution for a table, reclaims the unused space and defragments the data file.

**ANALYZE TABLE** Only analyzes table and stores the key distribution.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: I am using mysql version 5.7

Comment: but you using msql version 5 then its same